# Calculating z/w in polar form

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

## IT HAS BEEN ANSWERED, THANK YOU

So we have:

z = 7 + 4i

w = 8-i

I did this: $$7+4i/8-i$$
$$conjagate =\space 8+i$$
$$ (7+4i/8-i) \times (8+i/8+i)$$
$$(56+7i+32i+4i^2)/((8-i)\times(8+i))$$
$$52+39i/(65)$$

## **This is what I got using polar form:**

**Z in polar form**

---

$$Polar form = x+iy = r(cos(0)+isin(0))$$
$$ r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

SO

$$r (for\space z) =  \sqrt{7^2+4^2} = 2072/257$$

$$ 0 = atan(y/x) = atan(4/7) =14/27$$

therefore z in polar form is

$$(2072/257)*(cos(14/27)+i*sin(14/27))=z$$

**W in polar form**

---

$$Polar form = x+iy = r(cos(0)+isin(0))$$
$$ r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

SO

$$r (for\space w) =  \sqrt{8^2+-1^2} = 2024/255$$

$$ 0 = atan(y/x) = atan(-1/8) =-241/1938$$

therefore w in polar form is

$$(2024/255)*(cos(-241/1938)+i*sin(-241/1938)) = w$$

---

$$z/w =  (\sqrt(7^2+4^2)*(cos(atan(4/7))+i*sin(atan(4/7)))) / (\sqrt(8^2+(-1)^2)*(cos(atan((-1)/8))+i*sin(atan((-1)/8))))$$

$$z/w = 4/5+3/5i$$

All good, it works out!

Comment: They are not the same because you made a different mistake the first time from the mistake you made the second time.

Comment: What did I mess up in the first part, I just checked my equations and they seem fine?

Comment: Please show explicitly the steps you took while computing because you got wrong answers in both parts.

Comment: I have no idea what you've done, really; but your numbers in polar are not the same as in rectangular. Though they are very close.

Comment: I have added the steps i took for the first part

Comment: I removed the incorrect conclusion from the first part, and rewrote your correct conclusion with appropriate parentheses. You should also add your steps for the second part.

Comment: I have added all parts

Comment: I still cant seem to make it work with the second part? Any ideas  @CameronBuie

Comment: In the first part, there is no need for parentheses around the $65$. There ***is*** need for parentheses around $52+39i,$ for if not, then you're talking about $$52+\frac{39i}{65}.$$ As for the second part, you're doing fine, except you keep approximating. For $z$, $$r=\sqrt{55}\neq\frac{2072}{257}$$ and $$\theta=\arctan\frac47\neq\frac{14}{27}.$$

Comment: Thank you very much @CameronBuie

Answer (score 1):

So first off:

$$\frac {7+4i}{8-i} \times \frac{8+i}{8+i}=\frac {52+39i}{65}=.8+.6i$$
So In polar form this is $e^{arctan(\frac34)}$

Suppose we have a complex variable defined as $a+ib$.  Then in polar coordinates, this is equivalent to $re^{\theta}$, where $r=\sqrt {a^2+b^2} ; \theta = tan^{-1}(\frac ba).$

So we have

z = 7 + 4i

w = 8-i

In polar form, z = $\sqrt{4^2+7^2}e^{arctan{\frac 4 7}}=\sqrt{65}e^{arctan(\frac 47)}$

And w = $\sqrt {8^2+1^2}e^{arctan(-\frac 18)}=\sqrt{65}e^{-arctan (\frac18)}$

So $\frac zw = e^{arctan(\frac 47)+arctan(\frac 18)}$

If you do a little arithmetic, you see that the above exponent is equal to $e^{arctan(\frac 34})$, so the two are the same!